# String.Format in .aspx not showing rest of text after

Tags: asp.net

```
<div visible="false" runat="server"><a href='<%#string.Format("{0}removeAllItems=true", this.Page)%>' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove all items?')">Remove all items</a></div>
```

when I run this, it doesn't show the querystring portion, just the page.aspx.  I don't see why the rest of that string after {0} is being cut off.

Comment: the only one that seems to work is <a href='<%=this.Page %>?removeAllItems=true")%>' but then again I guess this.Page is not waht I want anyway as it's giving me ASP.pagename_aspx as the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the question mark probably has something to do with using data binding (`<%#...%>`) instead of simple output (`<%=...%>`).

String.Format is overkill, as you only want to concatenate two strings:

```
<a href='<%=String.Concat(this.Page, ".aspx?removeItems=true")%>' >text</a>
```

Or simply putting the second string in the markup:

```
<a href='<%=this.Page%>.aspx?removeItems=true' >text</a>
```

Comment: I don't need the .aspx as we've found.  Yea, don't need the string.Format but I still want to know why this does not work regardless of not needing it.

Comment: How is string.format overkill, in what way?  If you are talking memory fine otherwise it's really what your taste is on readability

Comment: ok it was the # vs. =.  this.Page also isn't giving me what I want anyway but at least I have solved the issue.

Comment: Perhaps it's Request.Path that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation is unnecessary; have you tried this?

```
<a href='<%#string.Format("{0}.aspx?removeItems=true", this.Page)%>' >text</a>
```

Comment: yes, actually tried this right after posting.  It still ignores the ? text after {0}

Answer (score 0):

Since it's ignoring the ?, try this:

```
<a href='<%#string.Format("{0}.aspx{1}removeItems=true", this.Page, "?")%>' >text</a>
```

The inline tag <%# is used for databinding, yet this.
Page isn't a databound property.  Switch that out to <%=, which is equivalent to Response.Write & see if that works.

It's hackish, but sometimes that's what it takes in asp.net.

E.g. if you're using StringBuilder to create a javascript string at runtime and you try StringBuilder.AppendFormat, you can't have any other braces besides the Format braces.  you can overcome that problem in a similar fashion to my answer using one string.format method and injecting "{" and "}".

The "?" issue may be a problem of codepage error handling withing databinding tags. For more information on this, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663

Comment: weird, I shouldn't have to do that though.  I'd want to know why it's ignoring ANY part after the {0}.  To me this would be a hack...sorry just being honest.  I really want to figure out wtf is going on and so far no luck on my side, this is a pain.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible explanation as to why you're experience problems with the "?".

Comment: ah, I didn't reload the page since your question was answered. sorry.